# How can I write a function that loops through this nodelist and updates my HTML based off the item I clicked on?

Tags: javascript

I have this image gallery created and I'm trying to figure out how to write a function that will loop though this nodelist and update my html based off the image I clicked on. I alredy have a changeImg() function at the very bottom of my javascript that changes the image src link based off the index that I clicked on, but I'm not sure how I'd do the same with text only since I'm not changing any links.

```
0: h1.services-cell_text
1: h1.services-cell_text
2: h1.services-cell_text
3: h1.services-cell_text
4: h1.services-cell_text
5: h1.services-cell_text
6: h1.services-cell_text
length: 7
__proto__: NodeList
```

So basically if I click on img-1, I want `<h1 class="services-cell_text">Digital Marketing</h1>` to pop up and then img-2 I'd want the h1 for img-2 to show up. Right now my code only shows the first `<h1>` tag of the image I clicked on, so if I click on image 1 and change the image to image 2, the image 1 `<h1>` still remains there.

Here is the HTML

```
    <div class="services-cell">
                <img class="services-cell_img" src="gallery/img-1.jpg" alt="">
                <h1 class="services-cell_text">Digital Marketing</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="services-cell">
                <img class="services-cell_img" src="gallery/img-2.jpg" alt="">
                <h1 class="services-cell_text">Website Development</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="services-cell">
                <img class="services-cell_img" src="gallery/img-3.jpg" alt="">
                <h1 class="services-cell_text">Videography</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="services-cell">
                <img class="services-cell_img" src="gallery/img-4.jpg" alt="">
                <h1 class="services-cell_text">Photography</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="services-cell">
                <img class="services-cell_img" src="gallery/img-5.jpg" alt="">
                <h1 class="services-cell_text">Consulting</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="services-cell">
                <img class="services-cell_img" src="gallery/img-6.jpg" alt="">
                <h1 class="services-cell_text">SEO</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="services-cell">
            <img class="services-cell_img" src="gallery/img-7.jpg" alt="">
            <h1 class="services-cell_text">Graphic Design</h1> 
            </div>
```

Here is the JS

```
                let galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll('.services-cell');
                let getLatestOpenedImg;
                let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;


                if(galleryImages) {
                    galleryImages.forEach(function(image, index){
                        image.onclick = function() {
                            console.log(image.firstElementChild);
                            console.log(image.children[1].cloneNode(true));


                            getLatestOpenedImg = index + 1;

                            let container = document.body;
                            let newImgWindow = document.createElement('div');
                            container.appendChild(newImgWindow);    
                            newImgWindow.setAttribute('class', 'img-window');
                            newImgWindow.setAttribute('onclick', 'closeImg()');

                            let newImg = image.firstElementChild.cloneNode();
                            newImgWindow.appendChild(newImg);
                            newImg.classList.remove('services-cell_img');
                            newImg.classList.add('popup-img');
                            newImg.setAttribute('id', 'current-img');

                            let newTextDiv = document.querySelector('.img-window');
                            let newText = document.createElement('div');
                            newTextDiv.appendChild(newText)
                            newText.setAttribute('class', 'img-text');


                            newImg.onload = function() {
                                // let imgWidth = this.width;
                                // let calcImgPos = ((windowWidth - imgWidth) / 2);

                                let imgTextValue = image.children[1].cloneNode(true);
                                newText.appendChild(imgTextValue);
                                imgTextValue.setAttribute('id', 'popup-text');


                                let newNextBtn = document.createElement('a');
                                newNextBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-chevron-right next"></i>';
                                container.appendChild(newNextBtn);
                                newNextBtn.setAttribute('class', 'img-btn-next');
                                newNextBtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'changeImg(1)');
                                // newNextBtn.style.cssText = 'right: ' + calcImgToEdge + 'px;'

                                let newPrevBtn = document.createElement('a');
                                newPrevBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-chevron-left next"></i>';
                                container.appendChild(newPrevBtn);
                                newPrevBtn.setAttribute('class', 'img-btn-prev');
                                newPrevBtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'changeImg(0)');

                                // newPrevBtn.style.cssText = 'left: ' + calcImgToEdge + 'px;'

                            }


                        }
                    })
                }

                function closeImg() {
                    document.querySelector('.img-window').remove();
                    document.querySelector('.img-btn-next').remove();
                    document.querySelector('.img-btn-prev').remove();

                }

                //Changes images
                function changeImg(change) {
                    document.querySelector('#current-img').remove();

                    let getImgWindow = document.querySelector('.img-window');
                    let newImg = document.createElement('img');
                    getImgWindow.appendChild(newImg);

                    let calcNewImg;
                    if(change === 1) {
                        calcNewImg = getLatestOpenedImg + 1;
                        if(calcNewImg > galleryImages.length) {
                            calcNewImg = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(change === 0) {
                        calcNewImg = getLatestOpenedImg - 1;
                        if(calcNewImg < 1) {
                            calcNewImg = galleryImages.length;
                        }
                    }

                    newImg.setAttribute('src', 'gallery/img-' + calcNewImg + '.jpg');
                    newImg.setAttribute('class', 'popup-img');
                    newImg.setAttribute('id', 'current-img');
                    // newImg.style.transition = 'opacity 1s ease-in-out';

                    getLatestOpenedImg = calcNewImg;
                }
```

[image]

Comment: Event handler functions receive a parameter which is the event that triggered the handler, so rather than `image.onclick = function() { ... }` you can declare it as `image.onclick = function(event) { ... }` then `event.target` tells you what was actually clicked. Then `event.target.parentElement.querySelector('h1').textContent` gets the parent element (the div the image is in) then finds an `h1` element that is in that parent div, then gets the text that's in the h1

Comment: how would I write that into a function though? because my current JS code works fine besides the fact I don't have a function that removes the current h1 tag and replaces it with the next image that I click on

Comment: I'd like to help more but there's a lot that's not clear to me in your code since it's not runnable, but maybe where you create a new container `newText = document.createElement('div')` or the newTextDiv you could append the text from the h1 -- or clone the whole h1 and append _that_, or _detach_ the h1 and re-parent it (since you mention "removes the current h1 tag"). I just can't tell from looking at the code where you'd want it.

Comment: So I added a picture showing what code the JS creates. I need the new h1 to replace the current h1 in the image, but also replace the original h1 from the html since it get's removed. 

The .img-window div is created from the JS code that starts with
`let container = document.body;
                            let newImgWindow = document.createElement('div');
                            container.appendChild(newImgWindow);    
                            newImgWindow.setAttribute('class', 'img-window');
                            newImgWindow.setAttribute('onclick', 'closeImg()');
`

Comment: where it says `newImg.onload = function()` that is what created the h1 tag, so I'd need a function that knows what Image I clicked on and how to replace that h1 tag with the correct index aka the image I clicked

Comment: Honestly it's unclear how you're explaining it what it is that you're after.